# How to change JavaScript function when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a doubt relegated to javascript function.

I had a button:

```js
function open(){
document.getElementsByTagName(“p”).style.display =“block”;
}
function close(){
document.getElementsByTagName(“p”).style.display =“none”;
}
```

```css
p{
display:none;
}.
```

```html
<button onclick=“open”>Hi</button>
<p>school</p>.
```

But I am facing a problem. When the button is clicked, the `open()` function is triggered.
And then the `<p>` element is displayed

But when again button is triggered the function `close()` should be triggered and `<p>` element must be closed

I am unable to change it
What result I want is

```
<button onclick=“open()”>hi</button>
```

And this should be changed to:

```
<button onclick=“close()”>hi</button>
```

Comment: Both of the function names are extremely bad choises for a name of a global function, they are names of the native functions, and overriding those might lead troubles elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Do you have double curly quotes in your code, or were they introduced by how you copied it here?

Answer (score 0):

On your button use a function that does both.

`<button onclick=“openAndClose()”>hi</button>`

In this function you can let a boolean value decide to use the `open()` or `close()` function

```
function openAndClose(){
   if(this.booleanValue === true){
      this.booleanValue = false
      open()
   }
   else{
      this.booleanValue = true
      close()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register a separate function for listening an event, where you can check that either it is the first or second time the button is being clicked, more like setting a flag and accordingly call open or close.

```
button.addEventListener('click', checkState);

function checkState(){
    if(check){
         open();
       }else{
         close();
       }
}
```